# Android EditTExt query

Tags: android

I stuck with one issue in my current application. I have one editText and i have set it Enables = false in XML file. I have to buttons also named as EDIT and DONE.

Problem.

When application launches it works fine. EditText is not having focus and when i click on editext keyboard appears and i can edit text in edit text.

```
if(v==Edit)
    {
        //PurchaseAddressdata.setFocusable(true);
        Edit.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
        done.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        PurchaseAddressdata.setClickable(true);
        PurchaseAddressdata.setEnabled(true);
        PurchaseAddressdata.setCursorVisible(true);
          PurchaseAddressdata.setSelection(PurchaseAddressdata.getText().length());

    }
    if(v==done)
    {
        Edit.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        done.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
        PurchaseAddressdata.setCursorVisible(false);
        PurchaseAddressdata.setClickable(false);



    }
```

**But the problem is when i click on editext keyboard is appearing.** I want when i press Edit button then only keyboard will appear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the `onFocusChangeListener` listener of the edit text field to this so that it hides the keyboard when focused.

```
boolean display_keyboard = false;
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener()
{

    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean arg1)
    {
        if (!display_keyboard)
        {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Then when the Edit button is clicked, set `displaykeyboard = true;` and move the focus back to the edittext

Answer (score 0):

try this code it works for me.

editText.setInputType(0);

and in onClick()

editText.setInputtype(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);